# Issue with getting data from two related model classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have tables:

```
Items{ItemId, Title, CreatedBy, CreatedOnDate}
Likes{ItemId, UserId, CreatedOnDate}
```

In ef I have this two models:

```
[Table("Likes")]
    public class Like
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public Guid UserId{ get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOnDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have a problem to get list of **items** that user likes. I have tried the following:

```
model = (from l in con.Likes
                       select new Item
                                  {
                                      UserId = l.Item.UserId,
                                      Title = l.Item.Title,                                      
                                      Likes = l.Item.Likes,
                                      User = l.Items.User,                                      
                                      CreatedOnDate = l.Ticket.CreatedOnDate,
                                      ItemId = l.Ticket.ItemId
                                  }).ToList();
```

I tried with and without `ToList()`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...get list of items that user likes...

Reading this I would propose:

```
var query = from l in con.Likes
            where l.User.UserId == givenUserId
            select l.Item;
var result = query.ToList();
```

But this is so far away from your own query that I have the feeling you want something else.

Comment: @1110: Cool! I didn't expect that :)